# What is canary monitoring?

Tags: monitoring

What is canary monitoring?
What does it mean?
Why canary?

Found a tool for canary monitoring here:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/tool/Canary.java?view=markup

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The symbolism is to the "canary in the coal mine"; miners in the old days, before electronic vapor detectors, would take a caged canary down into coal mine with them as an "early warning system" of dangerous gases. Contrary to popular rumor, the miners usually didn't wait for the canary to die; they were instead listening for the canary to stop chirping.

In this case, the program just sits there happily doing very little (basically polling HTableDescriptors which contain status data about Apache), *until* there's some failure, at which time it logs the nature of the failure (which can then be sent to a sysadmin via e-mail using some other system like event log sniffing).

A more "canary-like" system of monitoring is "heartbeat monitoring". This basically requires the system being monitored to send an "I'm still here and doing fine" message at set intervals. If the system misses a "heartbeat", the monitor knows there's something wrong. This is a little more akin to the canary chirping, as the monitor is just passively "listening" for these status messages, and the status messages are always a good thing (instead of the system used in your example which is actively watching the system being monitored and sends both good and bad messages).

Answer (score 4):

> An allusion to caged canaries mining workers would carry down into the
>   tunnels with them. If dangerous gases such as methane or carbon
>   monoxide leaked into the mine-shaft, the gases would kill the canary
>   before killing the miners.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canary_in_a_coal_mine

Answer (score 2):

> the miners usually didn't wait for the canary to die; they were instead listening for the canary to stop chirping.

Actually this is exactly what synthetic (or active) monitoring is all about [1]. There are lots of SaaS tools that does the job for you (https://www.site24x7.com/, https://www.pingdom.com), many for free. Some give API interfaces you can use to use to make customised version of your monitor (https://cula.io/).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_monitoring